# Null values are not inserted in Allow Nulls colums in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

My query returns false when some values are null, but my table allows Null values.

What did I do wrong?

```
cmd.CommandText ="Insert into BusinessTbl(BName,BAddress,BEmail,BMobile,BPhone,Cat_Id)" +
    "values(@bname,@baddress,@bemail,@bmobile,@bphone,@catid)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bname", b.BusinessName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", b.BusinessAddress);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bemail", b.BusinessEmail);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bmobile", b.BusinessMobile);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bphone", b.BusinessPhone);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", b.ddlbcategory);

con.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODNhs.png)

Comment: A .Net null is not the same as a database null, if a value is null in your code you need to pass DBNull.Value.

Comment: Besides the issue at hand, I think you also mean to use `"@baddress"` instead of `"@name"`.

Comment: @PeterB good eyes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a vexing feature of ADO.NET parameters; basically:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bname", ((object)b.BusinessName) ?? DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ((object)b.BusinessAddress) ?? DBNull.Value);
// etc
```

should fix you. If the `.Value` is `null`, the parameter *isn't sent* - it needs to be `DBNull.Value`. Alternatively, a tool like ["Dapper"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) helps avoid this pain:

```
con.Execute(@"Insert into BusinessTbl(BName,BAddress,BEmail,BMobile,BPhone,Cat_Id)
              values(@bname,@baddress,@bemail,@bmobile,@bphone,@catid)",
   new { bname = b.BusinessName, ... , catid = b.ddlbcategory });
```

(which will parameterize correctly, including the `null`s)

Comment: Thanks Marc Gravell